# jQuery Mobile Slider with Gradients and Labels?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider

I need to implement a jQuery Mobile slider with a few extras.
This is what we have implemented
http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-extensions/tests/visual/labeledslider/variable_labels.html

We added a nice blue to red gradient underlay but the problem is it won't support a swiping slide functionality on a mobile device. We can touch the slider at various points and that works but not sliding back and forth. I have my range set from 1-100 and interval of 1.  Notice that this example even allows a mouse to click and drag the slider back and forth very smoothly - that's what I want to happen via a mobile device.  I've left a question on his blog hoping he might have a new version coming out based on jQuery Mobile rather than just jQuery UI but I figured I'd ask in the meantime if anyone else has encountered and solved this puzzle.

I've looked at the options for the regular jQuery Mobile slider and see the data-theme and data-track-theme which sound hopeful for a gradient but I'd still be left with needing the labels.

Comment: Check this http://codepen.io/agcolom/pen/jtHmv

Comment: You could see if touchpunch (http://touchpunch.furf.com/) will add the touch events for the jQueryUI slider...